# How do I get my system to install updates again?

Tags: xubuntu, release-upgrade

I have been running Xubuntu 20.04.5 LTS since it came out.  I was going to upgrade to the next LTS, but I'm stymied by the requirement that I upgrade all existing apps first.  I cannot.

After making changes suggested by helpful readers...   When I try:

1. apt-get update runs normally
2. apt-get dist-upgrade seems to run normally, but...
3. apt-get autoremove removes nsight-compute-2022.4.0 and nsight-systems-2022.4.2
4. Whether or not I reinstall those nsight packages, do-release-upgrade says:

   Checking for a new Ubuntu release

   Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

So I cannot get the new release....  Please help

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS here and it is at .1  not  .5 .  There is not a new LTS release at this point that I know of.  Try running:   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
   and see if that helps

Comment: @4dummies `{}` i.e. "code" is best for text you wish to keep as is (mark text, click on that icon above it).

Comment: Download and install 22.04 LTS as that is the newest version. Try the commands and then try installing the newer LTS

Comment: Look in Ubuntu Live Patch settings and see if you can get 22.04 from there.

Comment: Live patch is in the top right of the panel bar or All Apps

Comment: As far as I can see xubuntu also has live patch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO\_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059”](https://superuser.com/questions/1744040/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-ava)

Comment: @Ramhound It worked, and resolved some of the messages, but I'm still unable to upgrade.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of `Software & Updates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md - They had to change their key signing key and this appears to have broken your install -

> Note We were recently forced to change our GPG signing key. If you've previously downloaded the githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg file, you should re-download it again per above instructions. If you are using a keyserver to download the key, the ID of the new key is 23F3D4EA75716059.

I posit that runnimg the following will import the new key (untested, im not by a PC)-

```
  curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg > github-com-key.gpg
  apt-key add github-com-key.gpg
```

After that, re-attempt the upgrade.

I posit you will get some warnings still.  If you want to remove these, look for duplicate lines in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-ubuntu2004-x86_64.list and remove the duplicate.  (my guess is you can comment out lines 51-53 in /etc/apt/sources.list)

Comment: What error do you get now? (you should update the question with it, tjen leave a comment here to "ping" me to look again)

Comment: It worked as far as removing all those messages, but I'm still unable to install the new release.

Comment: @4dummies The question was and is what error do you get now? And by error we mean actual error messages or any other issue.

Comment: @changanauto There was nothing I would call an error message.  Just the "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." and failure to complete when I try do-release-upgrade.

Comment: So do `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` (dist isn't used nawadays). If any error report back.

Comment: @changanauto Very helpful.  update says 2 packages are upgradable.  --upgradable lists two cuda packages with an odd "/unknown" suffix.  Removing them and their dependencies seems to get me closer, but apt full-upgrade does nothing and says so: "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: What is the output of do_release_upgrade ?

Comment: @changanauto IT WORKED!  There are a number of packages that were reported as problems, but I'll work through that elsewhere.  THANKS!